# PHP Sonata Admin - DataGrid filters to translatable property

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I want to filter the list by a translatable property.

```
/**
 * Get titulo
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTitulo()
{
    return $this->translate($this->getCurrentLocale())->getTitulo();
}
```

Admin class:

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('fecha')
        ->add('linkExterno')
        ->add('titulo');
}
```

And have the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: titulo in 
url...\vendor\sonata-project\doctrine-orm-admin-bundle\Guesser\FilterTypeGuesser.php 
line 64
```

Anyone can help me?

EDIT: Titulo property in class RecursoTranslation. This is the property that i want to search. The Recurso property showed before contains a RecursoTranslation.

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="titulo", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $titulo;

/**
 * Set titulo
 *
 * @param string $titulo
 * @return Recurso
 */
public function setTitulo($titulo)
{
    $this->titulo = $titulo;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get titulo
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTitulo()
{
    return $this->titulo;
}
```

Comment: It loks like you didn't define corectly titulo field.When you add undefinated field which is not mapped corretlly, or which is doesnt exitst you get similar error Could you paste your mapping information about titulo?

Comment: @user2482094 thanks for you answer. I paste the code down

Comment: Ok everything looks good. I don't understand your relation betwenen RecursoTranslation and class where you  try translate.  Does everything work propertly without translate?

Comment: @user2482094 i dont want translate, it's work fine. I want to search/filter in the list generated by sonata admin. 
Recurso have a Translation called RecursoTranslation, here is the property Titulo. Thanks!

Comment: I know that you want to add filter to sonata admin class. Everythings in your code are correct. It should work.  If you want to find reason of error you should debug what is wrong.

Does your edic/create admin form work propertly to "titulo" field?

Comment: @user2482094 yes, in create and edit work ok. If i find the solution this will be posted.